# transpose row to column but add the value of the first cell to each non blank cells of the row

Tags: excel, vba

Please excuse me as I am really new to this.
What I am trying to do is to transpose multiple rows into a single column but at the same time I need the value of the first cell of the row to be added to the values of all non blank cells from the same row. I managed to get the data for 1 row by using the code bellow but I am not able to make to proceed to the next row.

```
Sub Test()

x = 8
y = 2
Do While Worksheets("Data").Cells(2, x) <> ""
Sheets("Result").Cells(y, 1) = Sheets("Data").Cells(2, 1).Value & ", " & Sheets("Data").Cells(2, x).Value
x = x + 1
y = y + 1
Loop

x = 8
y = 2
Do While Worksheets("Data").Cells(3, x) <> ""
Sheets("Result").Cells(y, 2) = Sheets("Data").Cells(3, 1).Value & ", " & Sheets("Data").Cells(3, x).Value
x = x + 1
y = y + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

This is how I am able to do it manually but how can I make it to go to the next row automatically.

Comment: An example of your original data and desired results would be useful in helping you with a usefule solution.  What do you want to do with the blank cells?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it by using the following script:

```
Sub Test1()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim z As Integer

z = 1
Do While Worksheets("Data").Cells(z + 1, 1) <> ""
x = 8
y = 2

    Do While Worksheets("Data").Cells(1 + z, x) <> ""
    Sheets("Result").Cells(y, 1 + z) = Sheets("Data").Cells(1 + z, 1).Value & ", " & Sheets("Data").Cells(1 + z, x).Value
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    Loop
z = z + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Can someone think of a better way to do it ?

Comment: I'd use Power Query (available in Excel 2010+), if that is an option.  Pretty easy to unpivot, group on the original rows, do your mathematical transformations, then expand.  But if what you have works ...